# Connect to Google cloud server via python

Tags: python, sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to connect my laptop (and later a raspberry pi/Jetson nano) to a Server. The goal is to be able to send data to the server then process and evaluate it and send the output (GPS coordinates) back to the client (laptop/raspberry pi/Jetson nano).
Ideally, I would just plug in the public IP address of the Google Server into the code that is run on the client and connect to the server.

However, running the server code:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

and the client code:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

provided by: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/ .

Will only work with the default local IP address otherwise it returns a IP address couldn't be found error.

EDIT: The answer was more directed towards internet connection via the google cloud API. The solution illustrates this perfectly, however my question was not explicit enough sorry!

Comment: You mention **was changed to the google cloud server one**. What is that address? In most cases, you want to listen on all network interfaces. That address is **0.0.0.0**. Note: The Google Cloud Public IP address is not bound to a network interface. You cannot use that address. **127.0.0.1** is *localhost*, which can only be accessed from inside the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a large number of ways to do this, but I would recommend using either a GCE instance as your server, or an App Engine deployment. Cloud Run and Cloud Functions also would work. (**EDIT:** forgot k8s)

Note that when using a GCE instance you will need to open up your firewall as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls).

Also note that unless you assign a static IP address to the GCE instance, it will be ephemeral. If you use App Engine, you can just use `https://project-id.appspot.com/`  as the server address in your client.

You'll need to set up a simple web server using Flask, FastAPI or another webapp framework. It makes life easier to use a simple framework as it will take load of your hands.

You can have your client perform a request with the data it needs to send as parameters and have the web app perform magic and provide a response. I would highly advise to return a JSON response as this is more or less standard for APIs. (which your web app would basically be). Also, as you might know, JSON is easily converted into something useable in python.

See this very simple example below.

**server code**

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
longitude_divisor = 0.004167


@app.route("/api/gettimediff")
def gettimediff():
    longitude = float(request.args.get("Longitude"))
    # http://www.cs4fn.org/mobile/owntimezone.php
    seconds = longitude / longitude_divisor
    response = json.dumps({"seconds": seconds}, indent=4)
    return response


@app.route("/api/switch")
def switch():
    longitude = float(request.args.get("Longitude"))
    latitude = float(request.args.get("Latitude"))
    response = json.dumps({"Latitude": longitude, "Longitude": latitude})
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

**client code**

```py
import requests
import json


serveraddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
data = {"Latitude": 48.85837, "Longitude": 2.294481}


print("switch")
response = requests.get(
    f"{serveraddress}api/switch", 
    params=data
)
print(data)
print(response.text)

print("seconds")
response = requests.get(
    f"{serveraddress}api/gettimediff", 
    params=data
)
print(data)
print(response.text)
converted = json.loads(response.text)
print(converted)
```